# Test cases documentation compatible with cucumber, test automation and manual tests

Tags: cucumber, automated-tests, testcase

I'm working on strategy for my company which provides testing/development services. I implement both web and mobile apps test automation using Selenium/Appium, Junit, Cucumber.

In my company test cases are written in traditional form:

> 1) Go to X
>
> 2) Perform action Y
>
> 3) Go to W
>
> 4) Perform action Z
>
> Expected result: The application does ... .

But in Cucumber I use behavioral language which more or less describes similar action. I have also read this article: http://markoh.co.uk/posts/three-reasons-to-use-cucumber-for-test-automation and I wonder if we should write all our test cases in Cucumber language. For test automation, it will be just copy&paste to have a feature written. I assume this is web or mobile app with GUI.

- Is this a good idea?
- Have you hot any experience with such test
  cases documentation in long term?
- Can manual testers have difficulties in using test cases written is such manner instead of traditional language?

Any input appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

The main advantage in the Cucumber test cases is their reliability. You will not be able to change the test scenario without the code update. Also the Cucumber allows to figure out your common procedures that may be useful even in the manual tests. The test cases are self documented therefore we usually don't have any difficulties in the scenarios reading by any technical personnel. I succesfully used that approach in my previous job and I going to entry it also now. Also I would suggest to use the Cucumber background feature that allows to define the test prerequisites.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Sounds reasonable. Also I think that maybe requirements should be written in form of user stories ? Then it can be just copied to the .feature file. i.e.: Feature: Multiple site support
  As a Mephisto site owner
  I want to host blogs for different people
  In order to make gigantic piles of money

Comment: ... and thanks for Background tip :) looks like there is more to learn in Cucumber than I initially thought

Comment: Yes this is the ideal situation when you can directly use your requirements.